# Django Model Graph (pydot) Error

Tags: python, django, graph, model, pydot

I have recently started working on a big Django project with existing complicated model. I needed to visualize that model, so I decided to use django-extensions (namely **pygraphviz**). But unfortunately, failed to install **pygraphviz** on windows using pip, so I installed **pydot**.

When Running the following command on windows cmd:

```
python manage.py graph_models --pydot -a -g -o my_project_visualized.png
```

I get the following Error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Any Suggestion of how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You must use older `pydot`. Version 1.1.0 works for me. Install with:

```
pip install pydot==1.1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

pydot==1.1.0 doesn't work for me with Python 3.5. as pydot 1.1.0 is not compatible with **Python 3.5**

Using **pydotplus** worked for me.

```
pip install pydotplus
```