# django-extensions generating model graphs

Tags: django, python-3.5, pygraphviz, django-extensions

django-extensions works well for me with Django1.8 but I have started a new project with Django1.9, Python 3.5 on Ubuntu 16.04 and trying to generate model graph but getting following errors:

1. After installing django-extensions1.6 I run command to generate model graph:

`python manage.py graph_models -a -g -o myapp_models.png`

I get this error:

`CommandError: Neither pygraphviz nor pydot could be found to generate the image`

2. When I have installed pygraphviz I get this error:

   `Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
   execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
   File "/home/shaifali/.virtualenvs/drf-auth/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
   utility.execute()
   File "/home/shaifali/.virtualenvs/drf-auth/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
   self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
   File "/home/shaifali/.virtualenvs/drf-auth/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
   self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
   File "/home/shaifali/.virtualenvs/drf-auth/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
   output = self.handle(*args, **options)
   File "/home/shaifali/.virtualenvs/drf-auth/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_extensions/management/utils.py", line 57, in inner
   ret = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
   File "/home/shaifali/.virtualenvs/drf-auth/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_extensions/management/commands/graph_models.py", line 89, in handle
   self.render_output_pydot(dotdata, **options)
   File "/home/shaifali/.virtualenvs/drf-auth/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_extensions/management/commands/graph_models.py", line 152, in render_output_pydot
   graph.write(output_file, format=format)
   AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'write'`
3. As mentioned [django-extensions docs](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graph_models.html), when I try installing pyparsing==1.5.7 I get following error:

   ```
   Collecting pyparsing==1.5.7
   Using cached pyparsing-1.5.7.zip
   Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
     File "/tmp/pip-build-1_hzke3p/pyparsing/setup.py", line 9, in <module>
   from pyparsing import __version__ as pyparsing_version
     File "/tmp/pip-build-1_hzke3p/pyparsing/pyparsing.py", line 855
   except ParseBaseException, err:                                 ^
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax    
   ----------------------------------------
   Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-1_hzke3p/pyparsing/
   ```
4. I have installed pyparsing without any version and also pydot, I got the same error as was with only pygraphviz:

`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'write'`

5. I have also tried installing pydotplus as mentioned in another [stackover similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38403350/django-model-graph-pydot-error) but nothing changed.